How to update existing enriched events in read model in CQRS?
I use Kafka Streams to process changes of user data and events corresponding to the users' actions.  I enrich events using join operations (KStream-KTable) and then write enriched events to Elasticsearch.
There is a problem: user data can be changed by the user (email, name, surname etc.) We need to update this info in the Elasticsearch index.
I see the only way is to store events in KTable and join in with another KTable. Unfortunately this approach leads to overhead because streams are stored in the state storage.
Is there any better approach? Or maybe this task is impossible?

You can't do that with Kafka Streams. You have to implement your own agent that listens to user data messages and updates the data in Elasticsearch.
In order to make this agent resilient, I implement it this way :

receive a message
infinite loop

search into ES for 100 data that are outdated (first name is not up-to-date or last name is not up-to-date or ...)
if no data are found, break the loop
else update data and bulk update into ES


commit the message

I do it that way because there is potentially a great number of data to update, and Kafka allows you a limited time to process a message. If the processing of the message is too long, Kafka fails to commit the message and your agent receives the message again. Because all the datas have been updated, the loop exits immediately and the message is commited. You can also restart your agent at any time, it will just receive the message again and resume its processing.
